# How do I Login to Asp.Net webapp from separate ColdFusion webapp?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, coldfusion, navigation

I have two web applications, of different technologies, one is developed in ColdFusion and the other in Asp.Net.

Both applications have authentication implemented. The usernames for both applications are the same where as the passwords differ.

So here is what I wanted to do, I log in to my ColdFusion application and when I click on a particular button it has to navigate to the Asp.Net application, without asking me to log in again to that application.

This is the solution I came up with; I passed the username from the ColdFusion application on button click as a querystring parameter to Asp.Net url, where it checks if it has keyed querystring and if username exists then log in to the Asp.Net application.

It looks something like this `http://xxxxxx.com?username=xxx`
But passing username in the querystring is not secure, what can be done to make it secure? I'm thinking of encrypting the querystring, can this be done? Or should I follow another method to get this log in functionality?

Comment: How can you be sure that the usernames are the same 100% of the time?

Comment: When a user is created in either of the apps the username will be added in both the application tables...Currently I'm trying to encrypt querystring from coldfusion app using 3DES and decrypt it in Asp.net app

Comment: _"passing username in the querystring is not secure"_ - usernames are not private; they don't need to be secure - and should not be used alone to allow a login!

Comment: (Simply encrypting a QS containing the username is not secure either.)

Comment: Can't you use the same database table for both apps?

Comment: @DanBracuk: No we(ASP.Net app) cannot use the authencation table used by Coldfusion app, the password column is encrypted which we are not aware of.

Comment: This is solved though, we created a passthrough table, the coldfusion app inserts a guid for a user with timestamp and this guid is passed as query string to our app, Asp.net app uses this guid to authenticate the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a random guid to each user in both system's authentication tables. Authenticate them with the first system and pass the guid to the second system via POST. Grab the guid using the second system and validate authentication and initialize that user's session.

Answer (score 2):

1) Create a table in your .net application Called AuthorizedSessions (or anything meaningful to you).

In this table, store the username, a randomly generated string aka token, a date created, and a date field to track if its been used.

2) Create a script in your .net application to accept a username/password from your CF application, and to first authenticate that the user is allowed to login, and then generate a record in your AuthorizedSessions table and then return back the tokeng back to coldfusion.

3) generate another script in .net that will accept the username/token as a link from coldfusion.  This script should validate the username/token against the authorizes sessions table AND make sure that "date used" is null, since it should only be used 1 time.

4) In coldfusion, clicking the link in your application should route you to a new page in your coldfusion application that uses the `CFHTTP` server tag to send the username/password, etc... over to your .net script generated in step 2.  If you have SSL available, that would be recommended for transfering the info over.  Your .net should return the token to coldfusion, and from there, you can redirect via `cflocation` to your .net application, making sure you include the username & token for the authorized session.  Make sure your .net application marks the token as used in the authorizedsessions table so that a token can't be used over and over again.

I've used this method in the past for linking users from 1 application to another and its worked succesfully.  Its basically your own scaled down version of an open auth type token system.